# Processing Sketch "Array Out of Bounds Exception" (when converting string to int array)

Tags: java, c++, arrays, processing

I am a student working on my first robotics project. I need help fixing a program that was provided by the manufacturer when I purchased an IR camera (similar to the Wii IR camera). The manufacturer provided two sketches. The first is an Arduino sketch that takes the i2c input and prints it out via the serial monitor. I don't have a problem with this sketch, but am providing it for reference.

```
#include <Wire.h>

int IRsensorAddress = 0xB0;
//int IRsensorAddress = 0x58;
int slaveAddress;
int ledPin = 13;
boolean ledState = false;
byte data_buf[16];
int i;
int Ix[4];
int Iy[4];
int s;
void Write_2bytes(byte d1, byte d2)
{
    Wire.beginTransmission(slaveAddress);
    Wire.write(d1); Wire.write(d2);
    Wire.endTransmission();
}
void setup()
{
    slaveAddress = IRsensorAddress >> 1; // This results in 0x21 as the address to pass to TWI
    Serial.begin(19200);
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); // Set the LED pin as output
    Wire.begin();
    // IR sensor initialize
    Write_2bytes(0x30, 0x01); delay(10);
    Write_2bytes(0x30, 0x08); delay(10);
    Write_2bytes(0x06, 0x90); delay(10);
    Write_2bytes(0x08, 0xC0); delay(10);
    Write_2bytes(0x1A, 0x40); delay(10);
    Write_2bytes(0x33, 0x33); delay(10);
    delay(100);
}
void loop()
{
    ledState = !ledState;
    if (ledState) { digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); }
    else { digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); }
    //IR sensor read
    Wire.beginTransmission(slaveAddress);
    Wire.write(0x36);
    Wire.endTransmission();
    Wire.requestFrom(slaveAddress, 16); // Request the 2 byte heading (MSB comes first)
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) { data_buf[i] = 0; }
    i = 0;
    while (Wire.available() && i < 16) {
        data_buf[i] = Wire.read();
        i++;
    }
    Ix[0] = data_buf[1];
    Iy[0] = data_buf[2];
    s = data_buf[3];
    Ix[0] += (s & 0x30) << 4;
    Iy[0] += (s & 0xC0) << 2;
    Ix[1] = data_buf[4];
    Iy[1] = data_buf[5];
    s = data_buf[6];
    Ix[1] += (s & 0x30) << 4;
    Iy[1] += (s & 0xC0) << 2;
    Ix[2] = data_buf[7];
    Iy[2] = data_buf[8];
    s = data_buf[9];
    Ix[2] += (s & 0x30) << 4;
    Iy[2] += (s & 0xC0) << 2;
    Ix[3] = data_buf[10];
    Iy[3] = data_buf[11];
    s = data_buf[12];
    Ix[3] += (s & 0x30) << 4;
    Iy[3] += (s & 0xC0) << 2;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (Ix[i] < 1000)
            Serial.print("");
        if (Ix[i] < 100)
            Serial.print("");
        if (Ix[i] < 10)
            Serial.print("");
        Serial.print(int(Ix[i]));
        Serial.print(",");
        if (Iy[i] < 1000)
            Serial.print("");
        if (Iy[i] < 100)
            Serial.print("");
        if (Iy[i] < 10)
            Serial.print("");
        Serial.print(int(Iy[i]));
        if (i < 3)
            Serial.print(",");
    }
    Serial.println("");
    delay(15);
}
```

The second sketch is a Processing sketch that draws a visual representation of the IR signal being seen by the camera. This is where I am having the issue. Sometimes when I start the program, it runs correctly. I get a printout of 8 numbers (four (x,y) coordinates) and the blobs representing the IR signals can be seen via the Processing window. But more often than not, I get an "ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException" followed by the number of the index being called for the output array.

Based on my searching and requesting help on the Processing forum, it seems that there may be an issue with converting the string from the serial output of the Arduino sketch to an integer array in the Processing sketch. The only response I got from the Processing forum was a link suggesting that I add tabs ("\t") to separate the string elements before I try to split them and convert them. But that didn't really do anything in terms of fixing the Array error. I originally added a line to print the length of the array so I could see that it was correct (it should be 8), and the length of the array kept changing. I'm pretty sure the error is occurring at line 29 to 40.

This is the Processing sketch:

```
// Example by Tom Igoe
// Modified for http://www.DFRobot.com by Lumi, Jan. 2014
/*
This code should show one colored blob for each detected IR source (max four) at the relative
position to the camera.
*/
import processing.serial.*;
int lf = 10; // Linefeed in ASCII
String myString = null;
Serial myPort; // The serial port
void setup() {
    // List all the available serial ports
    println(Serial.list());
    // Open the port you are using at the rate you want:
    myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[1], 19200);
    myPort.clear();
    // Throw out the first reading, in case we started reading
    // in the middle of a string from the sender.
    myString = myPort.readStringUntil(lf);
    myString = null;

    size(800, 800);
    //frameRate(30);
}
void draw() {
    background(77);
    //while (myPort.available() > 0) {
    myString = myPort.readStringUntil(lf);
    if (myString != null) {
        int[] output = int(split(myString, ','));
        println(myString); // display the incoming string
        int xx = output[0];
        int yy = output[1];
        int ww = output[2];
        int zz = output[3];
        int xxx = output[4];
        int yyy = output[5];
        int www = output[6];
        int zzz = output[7];
        ellipseMode(RADIUS); // Set ellipseMode to RADIUS
        fill(255, 0, 0); // Set fill to white
        ellipse(xx, yy, 20, 20);
        ellipseMode(RADIUS); // Set ellipseMode to RADIUS
        fill(0, 255, 0); // Set fill to white
        ellipse(ww, zz, 20, 20);
        ellipseMode(RADIUS); // Set ellipseMode to RADIUS
        fill(0, 0, 255); // Set fill to white
        ellipse(xxx, yyy, 20, 20);
        ellipseMode(RADIUS); // Set ellipseMode to RADIUS
        fill(255); // Set fill to white
        ellipse(www, zzz, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have been banging my head against this thing for over a week now, but I don't want to give up.

Comment: Besides all the problem you've described, you have a bigger problem: your keyboard's tab key does not appear to work. As a result, your code has no indentation whatsoever, which makes it completely incomprehensible. You need to address this problem first, before trying to figure this one out.

Comment: Can you please point out exactly which line throws the exception?

Comment: That second set of code looks like Java, not C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I am not sure what you mean by it not having any indentation. Can you show me a link to code that is properly indented?

Comment: @KevinWorkman: The error occurs on different lines, but each time it is one of the lines that calls the index of the 'output' array. So that would be the lines with:     int xx = output[0];
        int yy = output[1];
        int ww = output[2];
        int zz = output[3];
        int xxx = output[4];
        int yyy = output[5];
        int www = output[6];
        int zzz = output[7];

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Yes, the Processing application is based on Java if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Techngro - Your original post completely lacked indentation. About 15 hours ago [someone else edited your question and nicely formatted it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38680304/revisions). You should send him a thank you note for making your completely incomprehensible code somewhat readable. Did you even read your own question, after you posted it?

Comment: What **exactly** is the value of `myString`? In other words, what prints out when you do `println(myString);`? Don't describe it, copy and paste it exactly.